# How to package a Kivy application for Android from a Windows machine?

Tags: python, windows, kivy

So I was following along this Python tutorial teaching how to make a mobile app using Kivy, and at the end they used Buildozer to package it for Android. I discovered that Buildozer doesn't work for Windows. I tried looking for other ways, but have not found any straightforward way that works for Windows.

Would anyone be able to link me a relevant instruction page or explain how can I package my Kivy app for Android from a Windows WITHOUT using a virtual machine?

Comment: You can use buildozer in WSL, but this isn't officially documented because no python-for-android maintainers are actively testing it.

Comment: @inclement Is there nothing built for windows? Like, this is still using something built to run using Linux.

Comment: No, we don't directly support windows. WSL is probably the best option.

Comment: @inclement I didnt mean buildozer specifically. Is there an alternative that does the job as simply but works with Windows?

Comment: No there isn't, except that buildozer via WSL _is_ windows.